# xamarin forms : List view with overlapping popupview on item selection

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to create a listview which would display a popup view in the corner of the item when a specific item in the list is tapped and this view would overlap on the other items of the list.

Lets say the list have three items Active, inactive, inactive and when I click on first item, it would display a popup view/frame which would overlap/render under the first item of list and over the other items in the list.

I am not sure if it is achievable and how can I do that? tried absolute layout but unable to get the correct value of the items in the list.

Can anyone help/suggest how to achieve it ?

[image]

[image]

I tried the below code on item tap:

```
  void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
            {
                var label1 = new Label { Text = "View" };
                var label2 = new Label { Text = "Edit" };
                var label3 = new Label { Text = "Delete" };
                var sl = new StackLayout { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End, VerticalOptions= LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand };
                sl.Children.Add(label1);
                sl.Children.Add(label2);
                sl.Children.Add(label3);
                var f = new Frame { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand };
                f.Content = sl;
                f.BackgroundColor = Color.AliceBlue;
                f.HeightRequest = 150;
                var bv = (sender as StackLayout).Children[1];
                //AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(f, new Rectangle(bv.Width - 20, bv.Y, 130, 500));
                //AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(f, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.All);
                //(sender as StackLayout).Children.Add(f);
    
                AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(f, new Rectangle(0.5, 0.5, 110, 25));
                AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutFlags(f, AbsoluteLayoutFlags.PositionProportional);
                (sender as StackLayout).Children.Add(f);
        }
```

it didnt work. The view is like few pixels in height.
[![enter image description here][3]][3]

Comment: first, create an independent template that works on click, then add that template in listview. or instead, open an action sheet on click.

Comment: Hi, the third image could not be seen. I will suggest that using **SfPopupLayout**, there is a [Relative positioning](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/popup/popup-positioning#relative-positioning) could be set below some view easily.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to use this way to achieve it,you could calculate the position of the custom `Frame`.

For example, if Xaml code as follows:

```
<ContentPage.Content>
    <RelativeLayout x:Name="mylayout">
      
        <ListView x:Name="MyListView"
                  HasUnevenRows="True"
                  ItemSelected="MyListView_ItemSelected"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding items}"
                  IsVisible="True">
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ViewCell>
                       ...
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </RelativeLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

Then you could add child view for this `mylayout`:

```
private void MyListView_ItemSelected(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    //Navigation.PushAsync(new MainPage());

    var label1 = new Label { Text = "View" };
    var label2 = new Label { Text = "Edit" };
    var label3 = new Label { Text = "Delete" };
    var sl = new StackLayout { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand };
    sl.Children.Add(label1);
    sl.Children.Add(label2);
    sl.Children.Add(label3);
    var f = new Frame { HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.End, VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.FillAndExpand };
    f.Content = sl;
    f.BackgroundColor = Color.AliceBlue;
    f.HeightRequest = 150;
    
    var Yposition = MyListView.Y + MyListView.RowHeight * TapIndex;
    mylayout.Children.Add(f, () => new Rectangle(MyListView.Width-120, Yposition, 110, 110));
}
```

According to the tap index, we can calcualte the `Yposition` of the custom Frame.

The effect:

[image]